# Lucas Sequence in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

The Lucas Sequence is a sequence of numbers. The first number of the sequence is 2. The second number of the Lucas Sequence is 1. To generate the next number of the sequence, we add up the previous two numbers. For example, the first six numbers of the sequence are: 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, ...

Write a method lucasSequence that accepts a number representing a length as an arg. The method should return an array containing the Lucas Sequence up to the given length. Solve this recursively.

```
def lucas_sequence(length)
    return [] if length == 0
    return [2] if length == 1
    return [2, 1] if length == 2

    seq = lucas_sequence(length - 1)
    next_el = seq[-1] + seq[-2]
    seq << next_el
    seq
end

p lucas_sequence(0)   # => []
p lucas_sequence(1)   # => [2]    
p lucas_sequence(2)   # => [2, 1]
p lucas_sequence(3)   # => [2, 1, 3]
p lucas_sequence(6)   # => [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11]
p lucas_sequence(8)   # => [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29]
```

**I'm having a hard time understanding the recursion logic behind this. Can someone explain how the computer is solving this?
Does the computer read the length and then add up from [2,1] until it reaches its length? If so, how does it continuously count down? **

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is the programming equivalent of mathematical induction. Given a series, assume that the problem is solved for the previous member of the series and provide the rule for generating *this* member.

So, consider just these lines:

```
def lucas_sequence(length)
    seq = lucas_sequence(length - 1) # <1>
    next_el = seq[-1] + seq[-2] # <2>
    seq << next_el # <3>
    seq # <4>
end
```

That says:

1. You want to know the lucas sequence of a certain length (`length`). Fine, first tell me the *previous* lucas sequence, the sequence that is one unit *shorter* than this (`length-1`). (That is the recursion: the `lucas_sequence` method, itself, calls the `lucas_sequence` method, but with a reduced length value.)
2. Add up the last two members of that shorter sequence...
3. ...and append the sum to that shorter sequence...
4. ...and the result is *this* sequence, the one you asked for.

And that's basically all there is to it! The only problem is that there is no place to start. We assume that for the seq of length 4, we have solved 3 already, which we get by assuming that we have solved 2 already, which we get by assuming we have solve 1 already... But we haven't actually solved *any* of those!

So we begin by *backstopping* the most degenerate cases:

```
return [] if length == 0
return [2] if length == 1
return [2, 1] if length == 2
```

Now the problem is solved if length is 0, 1, or 2, because we just *give* those answers directly. Okay, so if length is 3, we solve with reference to 2, which is known. Okay, if length is 4, we solve with reference to 3, and I just told you how to do that. Okay, if length is 5, we solve with reference to 4, and I just told you how to do *that*. And so on, for any length you care to give me.

Comment: so if you put in a length of  6, it already knows it because it's been counting up from length 2?  How does it know where to count up from if the length is counting down? How does it know the previous sequence if  I haven't given it to them yet? For example, if I just put lucas_sequence(6). How does it find the previous numbers if the length is 5 and I haven't given it and numbers?

Comment: No, it hasn't "been" doing anything. It does it now.

Comment: It _is_ possible to combine recursion with memoization, so that if you have _ever_ asked for a shorter sequence, that sequence doesn't have to be calculated again. But _this_ example does not do that; it is pure recursion.

Comment: @Irakaj93 please note that if length is provided as a non positive number it will result in a SystemStackError because there will be no way to close the loop. The first guard clause should read `return [] if length <=0`.

Answer (score -1):

So it is essentially a modified Fibonacci sequence. Best way to solve most structured sequences is with an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerator.html) e.g.

```
lucas = Enumerator.new do |y|
  a,b = 2,1
  loop do
    y << a
    a, b = b, a + b
  end
end
```

Then

```
lucas.first(10)
#=> [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76]
```

First we create a new `Enumerator` and then assign `a` and `b` to your starting values (2 and 1 respectively).

To generate the sequence we use a loop which will lazily yield the values to the yielder (`y`).

Here we push in `a` then we assign `a` to `b`s value and `b`s value to `a + b` in parallel to avoid overwriting `a` before the addition of `a` + `b`.

Comment: OP's assignment (looks like a homework) explicitly said to solve this recursively.  OP is asking how the recursive logic works.  Your response, while elegant, doesn't address the question.

Comment: @pjs very well although a loop is pretty much as recursive as it gets

Comment: Not so. Recursion is a loop but not every loop recurses. Anyway the question is to explain the algorithm, not improve it.

Comment: @matt this "recursive" method does not necessarily execute recursively either. I did not say all loops are recursive I said a loop is as recursive as it gets which is true. Homework or otherwise providing alternative and, inarguably, better solutions does not dilute the post but betters it and the OP. I did not argue against your answer in any fashion. Although I severely disagree with the idiomatic nature of the original "solution" your answer correctly describes the issue at hand and mine proposes an alternative to allow the OP freedom and direction to explorer.

Comment: "A loop is pretty much as recursive as it gets."  Can't agree with you on that.  All loops can be implemented as recursions, but not all recursions can be implemented as loops.  QED they are interchangeable concepts.

Comment: Responding to a comment you've since deleted:  "[Recursion in computer science is a method where the solution to a problem depends on solutions to smaller instances of the same problem (as opposed to iteration).](https://computersciencewiki.org/index.php/Recursion)"  Note the clarifying phrase "as opposed to iteration."  An essential element in recursion is decomposing a problem into self-similar subproblems.

Comment: @pjs right so it loops. The arguments may be different but the process is the same.